# How to Duplicate JTextField Content in Another Non-Editable JTextField Dynamically

Tags: java, swing

How can I copy the content from one `JTextField` to another, non-editable `JTextField` character by character?

Every character typed in the first `JTextField` should dynamically appear in the second `JTextField`.

Comment: Check my answer and feel free to ask further questions

Answer (score 2):

> Every character typed in the first JTextField should dynamically appear in the second JTextField.

You just need to share the model:

```
JTextField original = new JTextField();
JTextField copy = new JTextField( original.getDocument() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, looping through characters might not be the best way to copy the content of your first `JTextField` to another. You can solve this inline:

```
secondTextField.setText(firstTextField.getText().toString());
```

For more methods available for Swing components read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html).

**Edit:**
If you what you want is to copy the characters one by one as they are typed, think about adding an appropriate listener to your `JTextField`.

```
myTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
                          @override methods here.
                          };
```

Place:

```
secondTextField.setText(firstTextField.getText().toString());
```

in each of `DocumentListener`'s methods.